# WPF/MVVM - Checking A MenuItem Based On String Match

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm attempting to implement a theme-selection menu in a WPF/MVVM application.  I've got the selection itself working, but can't seem to figure out how to set IsChecked on the appropriate MenuItem with pure databinding (aka without breaking the MVVM pattern).

XAML:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Theme">
    <MenuItem Header="Classic" Command="{Binding ChangeThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="Classic" />
    <MenuItem Header="Metro White" Command="{Binding ChangeThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="MetroWhite" />
</MenuItem>
```

ViewModel:

```
RelayCommand _changeThemeCommand;
public ICommand ChangeThemeCommand
{
    get
    {
      return _changeThemeCommand ?? (_changeThemeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => 
      {
          ThemeManager.CurrentTheme = param.ToString();
      })); 
    }
}
```

The theming is being handled by Actipro's WPF control suite (http://www.actiprosoftware.com); as you can see, the current theme is represented as a string only.

My problem lies in figuring out how to bind IsChecked in a way that will mark the MenuItem for the active theme.  The way the XAML is currently structured, that would mean matching the current theme name to the MenuItem's CommandParameter.

Any tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are hard-coding all your themes. Better would be to create a class called Theme:

```
public class Theme : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Implement PropertyChanged event on this.
    public bool Checked { get; set; } // Implement PropertyChanged event on this.
}
```

In your main view model, have an observable collection of these, then fill it up with your themes, i.e.:

```
ObservableCollection<Theme> Themes { get; private set; }
```

In constructor, something like:

```
Themes.Add(new Theme() { Name = "Classic" });
Themes.Add(new Theme() { Name = "MetroWhite" });
```

Now your context menu should look something like:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Theme" ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" IsCheckable="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Now, this gives you a set of themes, and when you click on one it's Checked property is set. Now you can assign your Command to the MenuItems, preferably as part of the Theme class (i.e. Theme.Set() seems like a reasonable OO design to me). Should all be pretty straightforward from here on.

**Update**

*How do I enforce that only one theme is selected at once?*

Assuming you have a MainViewModel, extend the Theme constructor to take a reference back to the MainViewModel. Then in your SetTheme() command, iterate over all other themes making sure they are not Checked.

```
void SetTheme()
{
    foreach (Theme theme in MainViewModel.Themes)
    {
        if (theme != this)
        {
            theme.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    // Do actual theme setting .
}
```

*Why should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged?*

Because the above doesn't work if you dont. Sure, you could just implement it for Checked, but as a matter of good practice I recommend implementing it for all public accessible properties that form part of the interface. That way if you use this ViewModel with some different View later on that wants to edit these properties, everything will just work.

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner approach, thanks :)  But I think there's still a piece of the puzzle I'm not getting.  With this design I can set the theme in Theme.Checked's setter (don't even need a Command), but then I'm right back to where I started: the functionality works, but the MenuItem's IsChecked properties aren't mutually exclusive; we've basically just added a set of Theme objects mirroring the Checked state of the MenuItems, but there's still nothing comparing those against the actual currently-active theme (+making sure only one MenuItem remains checked at a time).  Make sense...?

Comment: I also don't see why Name & Checked would need to implement PropertyChanged, as in the example above, neither are ever being updated by anything but the MenuItems themselves?  Certainly we at least wouldn't need to implement it on Name?

Comment: In other words, imagine you select one theme, then the other.  Now both MenuItems will be checked (and both Theme objects' Checked properties will be true)...but obviously the current theme is only the last one you selected.  Nothing in the above implementation actually binds the MenuItems to the current theme itself - so while one theme is active, multiple MenuItems (+Theme objects) may still be checked.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, and accepted :)  I actually didn't realize it's considered good practice to notify for all public setters, will keep that in mind in the future :)